# Vuejs2: Issue creating a reusable method to get options text in multiple HTML select lists

Tags: drop-down-menu, vuejs2, vue-component, select-options

Vuejs2 (*or any version*) noob here.  I have several inputs and selects dropdown lists (ddl) containing different data that I want to get the text values from to pass with my form.  I don't want to write a method for each select ddl to get the text of each option.  I've tried the code below, but I'm getting an error if I try to use the one method for both ddl:

```
"Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at VueComponent.getText"
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<div class="food">
     <input type="text" 
            name="txt_myFood" 
            v-model="txt_myFood">

     <select id="sel_food" 
             v-model="sel_food" 
             v-on:change="getText(myFood, sel_food)">
         <option v-for="food in myFood" 
                 v-bind:value="food.value">{{ food.text }} 
         </option>
     </select>
</div>


<div class="colors">
     <input type="text" 
            name="txt_myColor" 
            v-model="txt_myColor"">

     <select id="sel_colors" 
             v-model="sel_colors" 
             v-on:change="getText(myColors, sel_colors)">
         <option v-for="color in myColors" 
                 v-bind:value="color.value">{{ color.text }} 
         </option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Vue

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {

      optionText: "",      
      sel_food: "",
      myFood: [
        { value: 0, text: "tuna" },
        { value: 1, text: "chicken" },
        { value: 2, text: "lamb" }
      ],

      sel_colors: "",
      myColors: [
        { value: 0, text: "red" },
        { value: 1, text: "blue" },
        { value: 2, text: "yellow" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getText(myArr=[], vModel="") {          

      var values = this.myArr.map(function(o) {
        return o.value;
      });
      var index = values.indexOf(this.vModel);
      this.optionText = this.myArr[index].text;
      console.log(this.optionText);
    }
  }
};
```

Thanks.

[FiddleLink](http://jsfiddle.net/codeXplorer/wpsoud1q/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is calling `this` on method argument.

See this example from your code:

```
...

getText(myArr=[], vModel="") {          
var values = this.myArr.map(function(o) {
...
```

Using `this.myArr` will make vue think you are trying to access the `myArr` in your data object. Since you don't have that in your object, you get errors like `annot read property 'map' of undefined`

So, don't call `this` on method arguments. Just use `myArr.map`

Here is your mode updated: http://jsfiddle.net/wpsoud1q/15/

Comment: that totally worked.  `this` can be confusing -- thank you for clearing that up for me.